# android layout images bad quality

Tags: android, android-layout, android-manifest

when I add images on layout it show in bad quality

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/sbackground" />
```

how to fix it?  (I need to fix it only without programmatically)

thanks

Comment: "android layout images bad quality"? I think there is nothing related to view and your image if your view not stretching the image then you need to improve picture quality.

Comment: When writing "XY looks bad" always include a screenshot. How are we supposed to know what "bad" means in this case to you, or even give you an idea how to fix that?

Comment: no image is good quality and big resolution (640 x 960 resolution)

Comment: We have no idea what your image looks like. Provide screenshot.

Comment: http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/846/ssettings.jpg/
this is example image it show on layout low quality

Comment: Thanks for posting the image, but that's not what we need here. We need a screenshot (a picture of the devices screen while running your app). In case you don't know how to take one: Connect your phone to your computer with the android sdk installed and run the `ddms` application from the `ANDROID_SDK/tools` folder. Then click on your device on the left and select `Device -> Screen capture` from the menu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think your images are stretching use the properties for imageview to get full image ..

```
 android:scaleType="matrix"
```

Controls how the image should be resized or moved to match the size of this ImageView.

Answer (score 0):

Have you compress or changed the format of image? while doing so sometimes images gets distorted. And make sure that, what you want to set in ImageView `android:background` or `android:src` ?

Comment: when I set background bitmap with this option it shows perfect

' BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
  options.inDither = true;
   options.inScaled = false;
  options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
  options.inDither = false;
   options.inPurgeable = true;'

Comment: Change your android:background="@drawable/sbackground" to android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher" or android:background="@drawable/icon"and try if everything works fine it means sbackground is not proper.

Comment: ok what you want to do.. set image to complete background or only to ImageView ? I told try with default icon image, which is already in your drawable folder

Comment: I need to change layout background image , and in eclipse layout editor it show in good quality , but on the devices it is very bad quality and I need to fix it