# Android - Bitmap Scale [QS Panel Background]

Tags: android, xml, background, scale

First of all ... I apologize for my English.

I am trying to add a background to the notification panel, the issue is that I have already achieved it by modifying the file qs_background_primary.xml located in SystemUI/res/drawable

This is the code I am using:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
<item android:drawable="@android:color/black"/> <!-- the image is very small, so add a black background -->
<item>
<bitmap android:scaleType="fitXY" android:src="@drawable/background_bg" android:gravity="center|bottom|clip_vertical" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" />
</item>
</layer-list>
```

Once the background with image and compilation is ready, one problem bothers me and it is that when I slide the navigation bar the image looks horribly, as if the size started from 0 to its original size once it was completely slid.

This is what the size looks like:
[image: what the size looks like]

This is what the full size looks like:
[image: what the full size looks]

Comment: The resolution will depend on the resolution of the picture and the graphic on the machine.  What is the pixel size of the png?  If you use an image with more pixels does it improve?

Comment: The resolution of my phone is 540 x 960. And to adapt the panel resolution very well I had to add 540x735

Comment: To me it just looks like you exceed resolution.  540x735 is not that great.  See following : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8193162/android-layout-images-bad-quality